# How to identify LaTeX errors in .Rd R help files?

Tags: r, latex, devtools, roxygen2

I'm developing an R [package](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr) and have used `devtools::check()` to ensure it builds correctly. I've successfully reduced the number of `WARNING` notes [from 7 to 1](https://github.com/ropensci/onboarding/issues/10). However, the final `WARNING` note is proving difficult to debug:

> WARNING LaTeX errors when creating PDF version. This typically
>   indicates Rd problems.

How can I find precisely which function is causing this error?

All the .Rd files are [here](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/tree/master/man) and all the R/Roxygen source code is [here](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/stplanr/tree/master/R).

Comment: @tonytonov agreed - was a duplicate. Solved!